# Can we still use Fn for dragging a window on new MacBooks?

Tags: mac, operating-systems, macbook, shortcuts, fn-key

On my older 2013 MacBook Pro, I was able to hold down the Fn key and drag any window my pointer was in. I've looked through the System preferences on my new MacBook but can't find a way to do this (I know you can do this using the three fingers shortcut when your pointer is on the top bar of the window).

Any idea if this is still possible on new Macbooks?

Comment: You can drag any window without forgrounding it by holding Cmd & dragging the title bar [or indeed many other move/resize/select actions]. I've never heard of the Fn behaviour you describe.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, that is useful for sure but I find it easier to just hold down Fn and drag the window by just placing the pointer anywhere in it. I've been doing that for years on my old MacBook.

Comment: What version of the OS were / are you running on the 2013 ?   That's probably more relevant than the model of the Mac

Comment: I was using Catalina until I got rid of the MacBook. Given no one seems to be aware of this functionality, I guess I could have installed an app/extension which gave me that functionality and then I just forgot about it -- that's one explanation

Comment: It's certainly a possibility. I've been using Macs 30 years & have never come across this functionality - though I can't claim to know every single shortcut a Mac can handle, there are just far too many ;) I did check this out on several Macs here, different ages & versions of macOS, just to be sure & none of them can do this. [They are all desktops, so there's a long-shot it was a laptop only function, but I'm not totally convinced.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked into this and found it is actually a functionality of an app I had installed a long time ago. For those interested, the app is called [BetterSnapTool](https://apps.apple.com/gb/app/bettersnaptool/id417375580?mt=12). Thanks for the answers, and sorry for the mix up :).